# Porque os navegadores renderizam a mesma página de formas diferentes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navegador-de-internet

Gostaria de saber o motivo que os navegadores leem a mesma página (HTML, CSS e scripts) e o resultado apresentado é diferente em alguns casos.

Comment: A resposta é simples: Pois utilizam motores de renderização diferentes, veja: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_de_renderizado

Answer (score 2):

Dentro do navegador, a parte responsável por ler e interpretar HTML e CSS é chamada de motor de renderização ou [mecanismo de renderização](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecanismo_de_renderiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o) (em inglês *rendering engine*), e existem vários mecanismos diferentes no mercado, por este motivo a página é apresentada diferentemente.

Pode-se dizer que o motor de renderização é um dos principais componentes do navegador, e alguns motores de renderização ficaram famosos e começaram a ser usados por mais de um navegador.

Por exemplo, o [WebKit](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) é utilizado pelo [Safari](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) (da Apple), e era utilizado pelo [Opera](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera) e pelo Google Chrome até recentemente, quando foi trocado pelo [Blink](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_%28motor_de_layout%29).

Há ainda os [Interpretadores de JavaScript](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretador_de_JavaScript), cujo objetivo é interpretar e executar os códigos JavaScript da página, e que também são reutilizados por mais de um navegador, como o [V8](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript%29) do Google e o [SpiderMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey) e o [Rhino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29) da Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

O facto de grande parte browsers adoptarem mecanismos de renderização diferentes, faz com que este se torne num dos principais motivos para que isto aconteça, vejamos por exemplo:

- Nalguns navegadores por exemplo, as fontes de texto usadas, não são
  as mesmas, e as vezes isso pode até variar consoante o `SO`, no entanto
  quando não se especifica uma fonte, aí cabe ao navegador decidir.
- Alguns navegadores levam mais tempo a implementar certos recursos, em
  comparação a outros.
- As especificações são ambíguas, e podem ser interpretadas de
  diferentes formas pelos respectivos fornecedores desses navegadores -
  algo que tem reduzido graças ao HTML5.
- Uso de diferentes recursos por parte dos codificadores web, exemplos
  pode-se ver o `-webkit-*` quando se usa o `CSS`.
- Bugs

Ainda falando de motores, de todos os browsers actualmente existentes, creio que *actualmente* nenhum usa o mesmo motor, quer seja para o *layout* como para a execução de *scripts*.

Fora isso existem vários outros problemas que são de pura responsabilidade do codificador, ou quase isso:

- Nem toda a gente que programa, segue as especificações da linguagem,
  isso aplica-se inclusive ao `HTML` - simples declarações como `<!doctype *>` ou ainda o `shiv` que chega mais como arranjo e por aí.
- Uso de recursos instáveis dependendo do ambiente - aplicar estilos
  com `js` em vez de `css`.

E ainda vários outros dentre estes. Mas creio que o maior problema mesmo, está relacionado a estruturação do código `HTML` - *semântica, esboço, etc* - e do próprio `CSS` - *propriedades* -, fora isso, o resto é de menos penso eu.

## Referências

- [W3C](https://www.w3.org/)
- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-dont-web-browsers-render-the-same-content-identically)
- [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530902/why-do-different-browsers-render-the-same-html-differently)